# Typing "this" inside a function/object passed as parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to achieve a function that takes a set of functions and force their type (they will be `Function.bind`-ed later).

Here's what I was hoping to achieve :

```ts
function testSA<T>(m: T & ThisType<T>): T {
    return m;
}

const TEST = testSA({
    a() {
        this.b();
    },
    b() {
        this.tata = 4;
    },
});
```

But this result in an untyped `this` (`== any`) inside both `a()` and `b()`

I also tried to unwrap each function and set its `type` parameter as such :

```ts
function testSA<T>(m: {
    [k in keyof T]: (this: T) => void;
}): T {
    return m as any;
}
```

But this result in an untyped `this` (`== unknown`) **and** an untyped `TEST` result (`== unknown` too)

At least, I tried setting another type as `this` to see if it was to do with the recursiveness of the declaration. For the `ThisType` way :

```ts
function testSA<T>(m: T & ThisType<{ tata: number }>): T {
    return m;
}
```

It yielded the exact same result (I suppose that ThisType dont work on objects passed as parameters?)

But for the `this`-parameter way :

```ts
function testSA<T>(m: {
    [k in keyof T]: (this: { tata: number }) => void;
}): T {
    return m as any;
}
```

**It worked**, I got as expected no error in `b()` but an error in `a()` saying that `this.b` doesn't exist.

It there a way to do this `this` type checking that works with a self-referring type? (or a workaround to achieve the type checking inside my function set?)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem using your first example [here](https://tsplay.dev/w65OeW)... This includes my first solution to the problem in the comments, but I was pleasantly surprised that you don't even need the solution...

Comment: In fact, you don't even need `ThisType`... So I'm wondering what the problem actually is?

Comment: @catgirlkelly you're right, it works on a playground... It might be something with my project configuration then, I'll investigate =(

Comment: @catgirlkelly indeed, in the playground the tsconfig noImplicitThis is set to true, and in my real project [it wasn't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitThis=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygZQIIB4AqAfABQC2AXIvogGRUAWMa+AngA4oGECUl1A3gFgAUIjGIATiiggJSUgG4RAXxEiICDFQCimagF5k6LNmJDR4gIbFuic+IfJGaAHQAjG0otjlAGhEOHrb2jmJQzi5QllGIhgAsXg5+KtwKQA). Setting it to true fixes the problem, but I don't understand why an error logging parameter impact the resolved type of an object...

Comment: Because it's not just an error logging parameter. Some compiler options change how the type checker checks types. Another one would be `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` and `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly TIL, thank you. Is this officially documented, somewhere? ([TSConfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitThis) doesn't mention this)

Comment: Hm, I think they should explicitly include that effect. [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) shows off what it does. Same for the [other one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments in an answer: It's not a problem in the code itself, it's a Typescript configuration problem. As we can see in those two playgrounds:

- [noImplicitThis=false](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQJIDsBmsBOAVAFgSwM4A8mAfKALygDeAsAFAihNMDaA0qLkqANayQB7FKEwBdAFwj2o0ADIRefJhixiJANz1GAX010tYFAFckAY3C4B3cLHzgAygEFioWAA8bSACb5EqDDgEaiQAFAC2kpgAlJHUBsxM6LDgRujcYXo69PGmVnYiAKL2mBQQtg6OIbQMYAkAhiFRcTUJreCKAHQARo2ZtczaADTxCT1N1YytzO0EHeB186UALH2tQ-HaUXr0xmYWVmV2TmrhsfKBSipqMSLNCUkpaaAZ9NrZdLlI%20ZhFJZQ2R0q1XqjTuUwgnTGegS6zoo1BwPBM3wcwWdWW0IGwzom3UQA)
- [noImplicitThis=true](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitThis=false#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQJIDsBmsBOAVAFgSwM4A8mAfKALygDeAsAFAihNMDaA0qLkqANayQB7FKEwBdAFwj2o0ADIRefJhixiJANz1GAX010tYFAFckAY3C4B3cLHzgAygEFioWAA8bSACb5EqDDgEaiQAFAC2kpgAlJHUBsxM6LDgRujcYXo69PGmVnYiAKL2mBQQtg6OIbQMYAkAhiFRcTUJreCKAHQARo2ZtczaADTxCT1N1YytzO0EHeB186UALH2tQ-HaUXr0xmYWVmV2TmrhsfKBSipqMSLNCUkpaaAZ9NrZdLlI%20ZhFJZQ2R0q1XqjTuUwgnTGegS6zoo1BwPBM3wcwWdWW0IGwzom3UQA)

So, to solve the current situation, I simply needed to add `"noImplicitThis": true` inside the tsconfig.json. Then the code sample from the question works as-is.

As to "why?": it seems like this parameter actually changes the way TS is computing the type of `this` inside the functions. This is currently an [undocumented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitThis) behavior though.